# I have a function mysql in nodejs and can't parse the result

Tags: mysql, node.js, iterator, rows

My function is:

```
objBD.query('SELECT MAX(ID_U) FROM usuario', function(err, rows, fields) {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

The result is

> RowDataPacket<'MAX':43>

I need the max number, example: 43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rows` variable returned by mysql's callback is an array, even if the result is only one row (as in the case of using `max`). To access the result you should access the first row of the array.

For example: `console.log(rows[0].MAX)`

This would access the first row of the array, and the MAX property within the object stored in that row, since each row is an object in mysql's results.

Comment: i swap "console.log(rows[0])" and the result is RowDataPacket<'MAX<ID_U>':43>

Comment: Can you try giving an alias to your selected column?

`select max(ID_U) AS max_id from usuario`

It _might_ have something to do with the output of `max()`

Comment: the result is same

Comment: Try `console.log(rows[0].max_id)`. This would access the property directly. I can't think of anything else...